# Converge / Diverge $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\big)^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\big)^2$$

$$2^n\leq n!$$

As $2\cdot 2 \cdots2\leq 1 \cdot 2 \cdots n!$

Therefore:

$$2\leq \sqrt[n]{n!}$$

$$2^2\leq \sqrt[n]{n!}^2$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}^2}\leq \frac{1}{4}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}^2}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: I think you should try to use the ratio test to show that the series converges.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $2^n<n!$ only for $n\ge4$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes sorry for no writing it

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
e^n  = 1 + n +  \cdots  + \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} +  \cdots  > \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}},
$$
it holds that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}} \right)^2 }  < \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^2 }}{{n^2 }}}  = \frac{{(\pi e)^2 }}{6}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac14=\infty$.

Comment: Correct it was correct for $\frac{1}{4^n}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $n! >  (n/e)^n$,
$(n!)^{1/n} >n/e$
so
$\dfrac1{(n!)^{1/n}} < e/n$
so, for any $c > 0$ we have

$\dfrac1{((n!)^{1/n})^{1+c}}
 < (e/n)^{1+c}
= (e^{1+c}/n^{1+c})
$
and the sum of this converges.

This question is the case
$c=1$.